# Running Docker on Windows Server 2019, Docker Engine won't start

Tags: docker, windows-server-2019, newrelic-synthetics

ultimately, I'm trying to run this command

docker run -e PRIVATE_LOCATION_KEY=NRSP-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -d --restart unless-stopped -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw newrelic/synthetics-job-manager

to install new relic's private monitor agent.

I get this error:
**docker: error during connect: in the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect: Post "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/create": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.**

Also docker desktop windows

Diagnose output

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources>com.docker.diagnose.exe
[2023-10-05T17:08:06.475232700Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.system][W] Windows version might not be up-to-date: The system cannot find the file specified.
Please specify a command.

USAGE: com.docker.diagnose.exe [options] COMMAND [options]

Gather and upload diagnostics bundles for Docker Desktop.
Commands:
  check
  login
  gather
  upload
  check-hypervisor
  detect-host-hypervisor

Options:
  -json string
        Output check results to the given .json file
  -path string
        Local path prefix where to store the diagnostics bundle.

Run 'com.docker.diagnose.exe COMMAND help' for more information on the command

Common use cases:
- Generate a diagnostics check:
    com.docker.diagnose.exe check
  This will print a series of diagnostic and suggest a way to repair the failures.

- Generate a diagnostics bundle and upload:
    com.docker.diagnose.exe gather -upload
  This will print a diagnostics ID you can supply for further troubleshooting.

- Generate a local diagnostics bundle to upload later:
    com.docker.diagnose.exe gather
  This will print a diagnostics ID you can use to upload with.
    com.docker.diagnose.exe submit <ID>

- Generate a local diagnostics bundle:
    com.docker.diagnose.exe gather <file>
  This will generate a local bundle in <file>.zip.

If -path is specified, place the diagnostics bundle in that directory. Otherwise the system default temporary directory will be used.

C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources>com.docker.diagnose.exe check
[2023-10-05T17:08:12.357204500Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.system][W] Windows version might not be up-to-date: The system cannot find the file specified.
Starting diagnostics

[PASS] DD0027: is there available disk space on the host?
[SKIP] DD0028: is there available VM disk space?
[FAIL] DD0002: does the bootloader have virtualization enabled? contacting Windows service: Get "http://ipc/hyperv/bootloader": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2023-10-05T17:08:12.385805700Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] ipc.NewClient: a0b1676a-com.docker.diagnose -> \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2 com.docker.service
[2023-10-05T17:08:12.385805700Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] (1406351d) a0b1676a-com.docker.diagnose C->S com.docker.service GET /hyperv/bootloader
[2023-10-05T17:08:12.385805700Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][W] (1406351d) a0b1676a-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /hyperv/bootloader (0s): Get "http://ipc/hyperv/bootloader": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2023-10-05T17:08:12.385805700Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] (1406351d-1) a0b1676a-com.docker.diagnose C->S com.docker.service GET /ping
[2023-10-05T17:08:12.385805700Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][W] (1406351d-1) a0b1676a-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (0s): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2023-10-05T17:08:13.401970800Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] (1406351d-2) a0b1676a-com.docker.diagnose C->S com.docker.service GET /ping
[2023-10-05T17:08:13.401970800Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][W] (1406351d-2) a0b1676a-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (0s): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2023-10-05T17:08:14.402540800Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] (1406351d-3) a0b1676a-com.docker.diagnose C->S com.docker.service GET /ping
[2023-10-05T17:08:14.403543000Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][W] (1406351d-3) a0b1676a-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (1.0021ms): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2023-10-05T17:08:15.403864300Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] (1406351d-4) a0b1676a-com.docker.diagnose C->S com.docker.service GET /ping
[2023-10-05T17:08:15.404402000Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][W] (1406351d-4) a0b1676a-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (0s): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2023-10-05T17:08:16.404796800Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] (1406351d-5) a0b1676a-com.docker.diagnose C->S com.docker.service GET /ping
[2023-10-05T17:08:16.404796800Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][W] (1406351d-5) a0b1676a-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (0s): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2023-10-05T17:08:17.405089800Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] (1406351d-6) a0b1676a-com.docker.diagnose C->S com.docker.service GET /ping
[2023-10-05T17:08:17.405089800Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][W] (1406351d-6) a0b1676a-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (0s): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2023-10-05T17:08:18.405797700Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] (1406351d-7) a0b1676a-com.docker.diagnose C->S com.docker.service GET /ping
[2023-10-05T17:08:18.406313400Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][W] (1406351d-7) a0b1676a-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (515.7µs): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2023-10-05T17:08:19.406572700Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] (1406351d-8) a0b1676a-com.docker.diagnose C->S com.docker.service GET /ping
[2023-10-05T17:08:19.406994800Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][W] (1406351d-8) a0b1676a-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (422.1µs): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.

[FAIL] DD0020: is the Hyper-V Windows Feature enabled? querying windows features: Post "http://ipc/windowsfeatures/check": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2023-10-05T17:08:19.416532900Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] ipc.NewClient: 404c1142-com.docker.diagnose -> \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2 com.docker.service
[2023-10-05T17:08:19.416532900Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] (b211083b) 404c1142-com.docker.diagnose C->S com.docker.service POST /windowsfeatures/check: [*Hyper-V* (Hyper-V)]
[2023-10-05T17:08:19.417045800Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][W] (b211083b) 404c1142-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse POST /windowsfeatures/check (512.9µs): Post "http://ipc/windowsfeatures/check": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2023-10-05T17:08:19.417045800Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] (b211083b-1) 404c1142-com.docker.diagnose C->S com.docker.service GET /ping
[2023-10-05T17:08:19.417954800Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][W] (b211083b-1) 404c1142-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (909µs): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2023-10-05T17:08:20.418458800Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] (b211083b-2) 404c1142-com.docker.diagnose C->S com.docker.service GET /ping
[2023-10-05T17:08:20.418458800Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][W] (b211083b-2) 404c1142-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (0s): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2023-10-05T17:08:21.419781200Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] (b211083b-3) 404c1142-com.docker.diagnose C->S com.docker.service GET /ping
[2023-10-05T17:08:21.420422700Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][W] (b211083b-3) 404c1142-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (641.5µs): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2023-10-05T17:08:22.421498800Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] (b211083b-4) 404c1142-com.docker.diagnose C->S com.docker.service GET /ping
[2023-10-05T17:08:22.421498800Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][W] (b211083b-4) 404c1142-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (0s): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2023-10-05T17:08:23.422553100Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] (b211083b-5) 404c1142-com.docker.diagnose C->S com.docker.service GET /ping
[2023-10-05T17:08:23.423273200Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][W] (b211083b-5) 404c1142-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (720.1µs): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2023-10-05T17:08:24.424250100Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] (b211083b-6) 404c1142-com.docker.diagnose C->S com.docker.service GET /ping
[2023-10-05T17:08:24.425371800Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][W] (b211083b-6) 404c1142-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (1.1217ms): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2023-10-05T17:08:25.426725500Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] (b211083b-7) 404c1142-com.docker.diagnose C->S com.docker.service GET /ping
[2023-10-05T17:08:25.427326800Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][W] (b211083b-7) 404c1142-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (601.3µs): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2023-10-05T17:08:26.427901400Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] (b211083b-8) 404c1142-com.docker.diagnose C->S com.docker.service GET /ping
[2023-10-05T17:08:26.429357200Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][W] (b211083b-8) 404c1142-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (1.3936ms): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.

[FAIL] DD0018: does the host support virtualization? prereq failed: does the bootloader have virtualization enabled?
[FAIL] DD0001: is the application running? prereq failed: does the host support virtualization?
[FAIL] DD0017: can a VM be started? prereq failed: does the host support virtualization?
[FAIL] DD0016: is the LinuxKit VM running? prereq failed: is the application running?
[FAIL] DD0011: are the LinuxKit services running? prereq failed: is the LinuxKit VM running?
[FAIL] DD0004: is the Docker engine running? prereq failed: are the LinuxKit services running?
[PASS] DD0015: are the binary symlinks installed?
[FAIL] DD0031: does the Docker API work? prereq failed: is the Docker engine running?
[PASS] DD0013: is the $PATH ok?
[FAIL] DD0003: is the Docker CLI working? prereq failed: is the Docker engine running?
[FAIL] DD0005: is the user in the docker-users group? prereq failed: is the LinuxKit VM running?
[FAIL] DD0038: is the connection to Docker working? prereq failed: is the Docker engine running?
[FAIL] DD0014: are the backend processes running? prereq failed: is the LinuxKit VM running?
[FAIL] DD0007: is the backend responding? prereq failed: are the backend processes running?
[FAIL] DD0008: is the native API responding? prereq failed: is the application running?
[FAIL] DD0009: is the vpnkit API responding? prereq failed: are the backend processes running?
[FAIL] DD0010: is the Docker API proxy responding? prereq failed: are the backend processes running?
[FAIL] DD0006: is the Docker Desktop Service responding? failed to ping com.docker.service with error: Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2023-10-05T17:08:26.500578600Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] ipc.NewClient: 6cc43f98-diagnose -> \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2 Service
[2023-10-05T17:08:26.500578600Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][I] (938aebaa) 6cc43f98-diagnose C->S Service GET /ping
[2023-10-05T17:08:26.501087800Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe.ipc][W] (938aebaa) 6cc43f98-diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (509.2µs): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.

[FAIL] DD0030: is the image access management authorized? prereq failed: is the Docker engine running?
[PASS] DD0033: does the host have Internet access?
[WARN] DD0002: does the bootloader have virtualization enabled? contacting Windows service: Get "http://ipc/hyperv/bootloader": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.
[WARN] DD0020: is the Hyper-V Windows Feature enabled? querying windows features: Post "http://ipc/windowsfeatures/check": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.
[WARN] DD0018: does the host support virtualization? prereq failed: does the bootloader have virtualization enabled?
[WARN] DD0001: is the application running? prereq failed: does the host support virtualization?
[WARN] DD0017: can a VM be started? prereq failed: does the host support virtualization?
[WARN] DD0016: is the LinuxKit VM running? prereq failed: is the application running?
[WARN] DD0011: are the LinuxKit services running? prereq failed: is the LinuxKit VM running?
[WARN] DD0004: is the Docker engine running? prereq failed: are the LinuxKit services running?
[PASS] DD0015: are the binary symlinks installed?
[WARN] DD0031: does the Docker API work? prereq failed: is the Docker engine running?
[WARN] DD0032: do Docker networks overlap with host IPs? prereq failed: does the Docker API work?

Please note the following 13 warnings:

1 : The check: does the bootloader have virtualization enabled?
    Produced the following warning: contacting Windows service: Get "http://ipc/hyperv/bootloader": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.

The Docker engine runs inside a Linux VM. Therefore Windows must boot with the Microsoft Hypervisor enabled.
Run:
 bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto


2 : The check: is the Hyper-V Windows Feature enabled?
    Produced the following warning: querying windows features: Post "http://ipc/windowsfeatures/check": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.

The Hyper-V Windows Feature is needed to run Linux containers in a Hyper-V VM. This is an alternative to WSL 2.

3 : The check: does the host support virtualization?
    Produced the following warning: prereq failed: does the bootloader have virtualization enabled?

The Docker engine runs inside a Linux VM. Therefore the host must support virtualization.

Check that hardware-assisted virtualization (either Intel VMX or AMD SVM) and Data Execution Prevention (sometimes labeled XD or Execute Disable or NX) are enabled in your BIOS.

Check your bootloader is configured to launch Hyper-V.

See https://docs.docker.com/desktop/troubleshoot/topics/#virtualization-must-be-enabled for Windows.
    https://docs.docker.com/desktop/troubleshoot/topics/#incompatible-cpu-detected for Mac.
    https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/linux-install/#kvm-virtualization-support for Linux.

4 : The check: is the application running?
    Produced the following warning: prereq failed: does the host support virtualization?

Is the Docker Desktop application running?

5 : The check: does the bootloader have virtualization enabled?
    Produced the following warning: contacting Windows service: Get "http://ipc/hyperv/bootloader": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.

The Docker engine runs inside a Linux VM. Therefore Windows must boot with the Microsoft Hypervisor enabled.
Run:
 bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto


6 : The check: is the Hyper-V Windows Feature enabled?
    Produced the following warning: querying windows features: Post "http://ipc/windowsfeatures/check": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.

The Hyper-V Windows Feature is needed to run Linux containers in a Hyper-V VM. This is an alternative to WSL 2.

7 : The check: does the host support virtualization?
    Produced the following warning: prereq failed: does the bootloader have virtualization enabled?

The Docker engine runs inside a Linux VM. Therefore the host must support virtualization.

Check that hardware-assisted virtualization (either Intel VMX or AMD SVM) and Data Execution Prevention (sometimes labeled XD or Execute Disable or NX) are enabled in your BIOS.

Check your bootloader is configured to launch Hyper-V.

See https://docs.docker.com/desktop/troubleshoot/topics/#virtualization-must-be-enabled for Windows.
    https://docs.docker.com/desktop/troubleshoot/topics/#incompatible-cpu-detected for Mac.
    https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/linux-install/#kvm-virtualization-support for Linux.

8 : The check: can a VM be started?
    Produced the following warning: prereq failed: does the host support virtualization?

The Docker engine runs inside a Linux VM. Therefore we must be able to start Virtual Machines.

9 : The check: is the LinuxKit VM running?
    Produced the following warning: prereq failed: is the application running?

The Docker engine runs inside a Linux VM. Therefore the VM must be running.

10 : The check: are the LinuxKit services running?
    Produced the following warning: prereq failed: is the LinuxKit VM running?

The Docker engine runs inside a Linux VM as a service. Therefore the services must have started.

11 : The check: is the Docker engine running?
    Produced the following warning: prereq failed: are the LinuxKit services running?

The Docker engine manages all containers and images on the host. Check the dockerd.log to see why it failed to start.

12 : The check: does the Docker API work?
    Produced the following warning: prereq failed: is the Docker engine running?

If the Docker API is not available from the host then Docker Desktop will not work correctly.

13 : The check: do Docker networks overlap with host IPs?
    Produced the following warning: prereq failed: does the Docker API work?

If the subnet used by a Docker network overlaps with an IP used by the host, then containers
won't be able to contact the overlapping IP addresses.

Try configuring the IP address range used by networks: in your docker-compose.yml.
See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#ipv4_address-ipv6_address


Please investigate the following 3 issues:

1 : The test: does the bootloader have virtualization enabled?
    Failed with: contacting Windows service: Get "http://ipc/hyperv/bootloader": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.

The Docker engine runs inside a Linux VM. Therefore Windows must boot with the Microsoft Hypervisor enabled.
Run:
 bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto


2 : The test: is the Hyper-V Windows Feature enabled?
    Failed with: querying windows features: Post "http://ipc/windowsfeatures/check": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.

The Hyper-V Windows Feature is needed to run Linux containers in a Hyper-V VM. This is an alternative to WSL 2.

3 : The test: is the Docker Desktop Service responding?
    Failed with: failed to ping com.docker.service with error: Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.

The Docker Desktop Service is needed to start the Docker engine. Open the list of Services and configure the Docker Desktop Service to start automatically.
```

So I've tried serval fixes I've found here and else where including
"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchDaemon

I've turned on Hypervisor as well. Does this error look like a firewall issue?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you enabled the hypervisor option (I assume you mean windows features - > Hyper-v),  it's less clear if you enabled it in the bootloader.

Please confirm if you run `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto`
and if so, post the output of a fresh run of the docker diagnostic tool. That should give you a solution.